# Traefik proxy routing NiFi UI on Docker

Tags: docker-compose, apache-nifi, docker-swarm, traefik

I am trying to dockerise the 3 services Zookeeper, NiFi and NiFi Registry below is the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    # configuration manager for NiFi
    zookeeper:
        hostname: myzookeeper
        # container_name: zookeeper_container_persistent
        image: zookeeper:latest  
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
        networks:
            - apache-nifi-internal
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
                delay: 5s
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 120s
# version control for nifi flows
    registry:
        user: root
        hostname: myregistry
        # container_name: registry_container_persistent
        image: apache/nifi-registry:latest 
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            - LOG_LEVEL=INFO
            - NIFI_REGISTRY_DB_DIR=/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database
            - NIFI_REGISTRY_FLOW_PROVIDER=file
            - NIFI_REGISTRY_FLOW_STORAGE_DIR=/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/flow_storage
        volumes:
            - nifi_registry_database:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database
            - nifi_registry_flow_storage:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/flow_storage
        networks:
            - apache-nifi-internal
            - traefik_webgateway
        deploy:
            labels:
                # traefik
                - traefik.enable=true
                # service
                - traefik.http.services.nifi-registry.loadbalancer.server.port=18080
                # middlewares
                - traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-registry-prefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/nifi-registry
                - traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-registry-headers.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https
                # - traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-registry-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
                # Routers
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-registry.middlewares=nifi-registry-prefix,nifi-registry-headers
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-registry.service=nifi-registry
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-registry.entrypoints=$TRAEFIK_HTTPS_ENTRYPOINT
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-registry.tls=true
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-registry.rule=Host(`$DOCKER_HOST_URL`) && PathPrefix(`/nifi-registry`)
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
                delay: 120s
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 60s
    nifi:
        user: root
        hostname: mynifi
        # container_name: nifi_container_persistent
        image: apache/nifi:latest
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8443
            - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_CONTEXT_PATH=/
            # - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
            # - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=admin
            # - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=ctsBtRBKHRAx69EqUghvvgEvjnaLjFEB
            # - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
            # - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=myzookeeper:2181
            # - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=30 sec
            # - NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY='12345678901234567890A'
            # - DOCKER_HEALTHCHECK_TEST=curl $DOCKER_HOST_URL/nifi/
        # healthcheck:
        #     test: "${DOCKER_HEALTHCHECK_TEST:-curl $DOCKER_HOST_URL/nifi/}"
        #     interval: "60s"
        #     timeout: "3s"
        #     start_period: "5s"
        #     retries: 5
        volumes:
            - nifi_database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
            - nifi_flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
            - nifi_content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
            - nifi_provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
            - nifi_state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
            - nifi_logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
            - nifi_conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
        networks:
            - apache-nifi-internal
            - traefik_webgateway
        deploy:
            labels:
                # traefik
                - traefik.enable=true
                # service
                - traefik.http.services.nifi-flow.loadbalancer.server.port=8443
                # middlewares
                - traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-prefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/nifi
                - traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https
                # - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
                # Routers
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.middlewares=nifi-prefix,nifi-headers
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.service=nifi-flow
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.entrypoints=$TRAEFIK_HTTPS_ENTRYPOINT
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.tls=true
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.rule=Host(`$DOCKER_HOST_URL`) && PathPrefix(`/nifi`)
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
                delay: 120s
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 60s
            
networks:   
  apache-nifi-internal:
  traefik_webgateway:
    external: true
            
volumes:    
  nifi_conf: {external: true}
  nifi_database_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_flowfile_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_content_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_provenance_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_state: {external: true}
  nifi_logs: {external: true}
  nifi_registry_database: {external: true}
  nifi_registry_flow_storage: {external: true}
  # nifi_database_repository:
  #   external: true
```

When I try to access my host domain along with the `/nifi` that is `https://domain_name/nifi/`

[image: ![image|476x107](upload://xmTzwD059zuKdPC7GuTfkoAXdNf.png)]

when I trying this link `https://domain_name/nifi/nifi/` I get the below error message

[image]

I should be able to access the NiFi UI from my domain using the `https://domain_name/nifi/` what could be the issue that is causing the error, any ideas or suggestions would be really helpful

Comment: you didn't define DOCKER_HOST_URL and TRAEFIK_HTTPS_ENTRYPOINT env variables

Comment: tha path needs to be /nifi-registry not /nifi

Comment: The `$DOCKER_HOST_URL` and  `$TRAEFIK_HTTPS_ENTRYPOINT` are variables defined in the gitlab CI pipeline. 

For the path, `/nifi` I am having issues to access the NiFi UI which is the error message that I get above

Comment: yes because you have this line that will limit your access:
- traefik.http.routers.nifi-registry.rule=Host(`$DOCKER_HOST_URL`) && PathPrefix(`/nifi-registry`)

Comment: you're telling traefik only allow paths starting with /nifi-registry but you're asking for /nifi